# Please migrate this question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration

Can someone migrate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163582/321731) to a more appropriate place. I tried flagging it, but was denied because I already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a chance of looking like an idiot and migrated it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8522/using-kde-in-debian-squeeze).  (Somewhere in the dark recesses of my memory, KDE and Debian are associated with Linux.)

Comment: Well, there's always the chance that the asker was actually using Debian GNU/HURD or Debian GNU/kFreeBSD, but those are presumably also on topic there so it shouldn't be an issue ;-P